# any compiler option available for catching "using address of a local variable"?

Tags: c++, local-variables

I have an object created in a local block , and if I use the address of that local member , outside of the local block, what should be the behavior?

In the sample code below, I see that the destructor is called for B, but still the address of B is valid and value set B.b_i = 100; is also still there.

I think

1. B is stored on stack , so the address is valid.
2. Value of A.p_b->b_i should also be on stack and nobody can overwrite
   it until I am inside the function.

Is my understanding correct ?
Will there be any difference in RELEASE and DEBUG build ? Because in release builds A.p_b->b_i is junk (Not all times, but some times I see this issue).

I am sure that it is not good practice to use address of members of local block.
But want to understand how it is different for REL and DBG builds.
How can I find this kind of occurrences in all my project? Is there any compiler option available in GCC/VC++ or clang?

```
struct b
{
    int b_i;
    ~b()
    {
        printf("Destructor called \n");
    }
};

struct a
{
    b* p_b;
    int a_i;
};

main()
{
    a A;
    {
        b B;
        B.b_i = 100;
        A.p_b = &B;
    }
    printf("%d", A.p_b->b_i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you're looking at is UB.  The moment you try and use `a.p_b` in the `printf` anything could happen.  There is no warning that will catch this because how should the compiler know when you assign it that you plan to use it later when it's not valid?

Comment: Clang has the option -Weverything, and MSVC has /Wall, since these do not give you a warning, you are likely out of luck. GCC seems to give you a warning with -Wuninitialized (included in -Wall) and -O1 or higher (since gcc does not do the necessary analysis to detect certain problems at -O0), but that does not point to the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: Most modern compilers are capable of giving warnings about such things, but are configured NOT to by default.     Read documentation for your compiler to work out how to enable more warnings.